# PHP POST always get's default value of HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm working on some extensions to a 20 year old PHP code. Now I needed to add a new text input field and process the data as in all previously existing text input fields. Evrything works fine except for this new input.

I've got a HTML form:

```
<form action="form.php?<?php echo SID; ?>" method="post">
  <?php echo "<div id=\"inputheader-title\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"".$new.$i.'[position_new]'."\" size=\"3\" maxlength=\"2\" value=\"".$i."\">. Entry</div>"; ?>
  [...]
<input class="button" type="image" src="<?php echo $HTML_IMG; ?>/send.png">
</form>
```

[...] denotes further input fields, which are all working fine. All text input fields are using the same pattern.

The source code for the text field within my browser looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="old1[position_new]" size="3" maxlength="2" value="1">
```

Which looks fine to me. But when I send the form data the value for **old1[position_new]** is always default in PHP's `$_POST`. All other data is correct (as inserted into the form fields). I checked that with `var_dump($_POST)`

When I examine the data sent by the browser I can see the modified value, but when it comes to PHP the data seems altered, despite it isn't processed any further.

**In short:**
I entered: 3

Default value is: `["position_new"]=> string(1) "1"`

The browser shows: `["position_new"]=> string(1) "3"`

```
var_dump($_POST) shows: ["position_new"]=> string(1) "1"
```

Comment: `name="old1[position_new][]"` should works for you.

Comment: Indeed! Now I see an array containing three strings ("3", "1", "1"). Why is this (and only this) input data processed as array? And cann I circumvent this?

Comment: if you have same name of the input fields then you should use `old1[position_new][]` and access the values as an array, OR other option is alter the name of input fields like `old1[position_new]`, `old2[position_new]`, `old3[position_new]`

Comment: Makes sense. But why is it working for other inputs like `<input type="text" name="old1[art]" size="15" maxlength="50" value="Lecture">` which gives me `old1["art"] => string(7) "Lecture"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP transforms fields with `[]` in name into an array. If you don't want this, remove `[` and `]` from field name.

```
<?php
  var_dump($_REQUEST);
  echo '<pre>'.print_r($_REQUEST,true).'</pre>';
?>
<form action="/test.php" method="post" name="myform">
  <input type="text" name="old1[position_new]" size="3" maxlength="2" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="old1[art]" size="15" maxlength="50" value="Lecture">
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="save">
</form>
```

In this example, with your fields names, array is correctly populated.
Check for a duplicate field with same name with a default value in your html code.

Comment: What I want is `["old1"]=> array(14) {["position_new"]=> string(1) "3", ["art"]=> string(7) "Lecture"}`. But what I get is `["old1"]=> array(14) {["position_new"]=> string(1) "1", ["art"]=> string(7) "Lecture"}`. So the array is correct, but not the value. The value of ["art"] instead is correct. But the input field is defined the same way as the one for position_new (`name="old1[art]"`).

Comment: Indeed there were duplicate fields.  Haven't thought of this simple solution. Thanks a lot.